# PDF::Toolkit.pdftotext not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdftk, pdftotext

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where used `PDF:Toolkit`. Everything work file like `open pdf, pdf-to-text` working well in local.

But when i uploaded code on server then always read any pdf blank. No any contents `read inside PDF file.`

```
PDF::Toolkit.pdftotext(@document.attachment.path,"-layout")
```

Output nil of every PDF using above syntax.

I tried lots but not found any issue.

Anyone have a idea.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have incorrect permissions on the server.

Comment: No, permission not an issue on server. I checked it first.